# Why is the service worker registration on my my application causing the network protocol violation error when opening other page links?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker, web2py

I have created a PWA with web2py but now I am facing a problem of

> The site at (page address) has experienced a network protocol violation that cannot be repaired.

when trying to open other pages on the app after it has loaded & the service worker is registered.

This is my service worker code:

```
window.onload = () =>
{
'use strict';

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
navigator.serviceWorker.register('https://www.example.com/sw.js');
}
}

Notification.requestPermission(result => {
if (result === 'granted') {
showNotification('Welcome to Sesoa™', 'Search for what you are looking for')
}
});

function showNotification(title, message) {
if ('Notification' in window) {
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
  registration.showNotification(title, {
    body: message,
    tag: 'sesoa',
    icon:'/init/static/images/icon_192x192.png',
    badge:'/init/static/images/icon_128x128.png',
    vibrate: [200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100]
  });
});
}
}
```

What i figured is that when I remove the location of the service worker & leave the quotation marks blank like in the code portion below all app pages open up as expect, the whole app functions properly

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
navigator.serviceWorker.register('');
}
```

But when I replace the address like below the problems begin

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
navigator.serviceWorker.register('https://www.example.com/sw.js');
}
```

How can I resolve this problem?